# Silencing STDERR and warnings

Tags: perl

How does `warn 4` differ from `print STDERR 4`?

```
perl -e 'local *STDERR; warn 4'
```

(output still goes to `STDERR`)

```
perl -e 'local *STDERR; print STDERR 4'
```

(no output here)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `warn` triggers `$SIG{__WARN__}`.
- `warn` doesn't use `$\` or `$,`.
- And `warn` apparently uses the file handle in the original `STDERR`, as you've demonstrated<sup>[1]</sup>.

---

1. Not quite. Your code could also demonstrate that `warn` uses fd 2 directly, but that's disproven by

   ```
   close(STDOUT);
   close(STDERR);
   open(STDERR, '>file');
   warn(fileno(STDERR)."abc");  # 1abc
   ```

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't understand what you mean by `fd 2` and `STDERR`. So `STDERR` is original, and `fd 2` is perl stderr?

Comment: All I said about `fd 2` is that it's not relevant here. So ignore that. `local *STDERR` creates a new `STDERR`. `warn` uses the original `STDERR`.

Comment: tnx, as I understand now there are three things: `fd 2`, original STDERR (from perl start), and current STDERR

Comment: Something's wrong with my explanation (incomplete?) because it doesn't explain the behaviour of Vassilii Khachaturov's code. I shall study this further today.

Comment: Built-in warn handler's relationship with the standard error is special. See [util.c](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/083ace8f9342a384107f7068fbedccaffa078b08:/util.c) Perl_write_to_stderr() which is at the heart of the Perl_warn() chain

Answer (score 4):

You **haven't** *silenced* the `STDERR` handle yet.  In order to really *silence* it, you need to say:

```
perl -e 'local *STDERR; open(STDERR, ">/dev/null") or die $!; warn 4'
```

---

[`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) tells:

> As the `'IGNORE'` hook is not supported by `__WARN__`, you can disable
>   warnings using the empty subroutine:
>
> ```
>  local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {};
> ```

Comment: tnx, but I'm familiar with `%SIG` and wander why `local *STDERR; print STDERR 4` works as expected while `warn` doesn't

Comment: @mpapec Because `warn 4` and `print STDERR 4` are **not** equivalent.  Saying `warn` would cause perl to send a signal, and in the other example, you're writing to a FD.

Comment: btw, I've modified your one liner to temporary disable all STDERR output `perl -e '{ local *STDERR; open STDERR, ">", \my$o or die $!; warn 4; } warn 6'` Should also work under strawberry.

Comment: @mpapec Yup, you can also say `open STDERR, ">NULL"` (that a full 4 characters more, I know).

Answer (score 2):

`local` here only says that the typeglob `STDERR` is local from this point on, it doesn't change anything with STDERR handle already seen by sig warn default handler by the time you enter this block. You need to reopen the handle to something else if you want to really silence STDERR.

If you want to silence it locally and then restore, here's how to do it, if you really must insist to resort to low-level globs and handles:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
sub f() {
    local *STDERR;
    open STDERR, '>/dev/null';
    warn 4;
}
warn 3;
f();
warn 5;
```

Comment: why then `perl -e 'local *STDERR; print STDERR 4'` works as expected? No `open()` here?

Comment: since the question changed, I have edited the answer a bit as well :-) The print is lexically bound to the STDERR declared in the local, which isn't open yet...

Comment: Re: "it doesn't change anything with STDERR yet. " Yes it does. `perl -E"say *STDERR{IO} || '-'; local *STDERR; say *STDERR{IO} || '-';"`

Comment: Our posts crossed ;-)